# Session not working in Laravel 4

Tags: php, session, laravel-4

I have a problem with Session that won't persist.

In controller I have a function that loads a article for editing

```
public function getEdit($id)
{
    try {
        $news = News::findOrFail($id);
        View::share('title', Lang::get('admin.editNews').": ".$news->title);
        View::share('news', $news);
        $this->layout->content = View::make('news.editNews');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Session::flash('message', Lang::get('admin.noSuchNews'));
        Session::flash('notif', 'danger');
        return Redirect::to("news");
    }
}
```

And I have another function - index, that should display these flash messages.

```
public function getIndex()
{
    var_dump(Session::get('message'));
}
```

Session is just not persisting. Not working with `Session::flash`, not working with `Session::put`.

`Session::get('message')` is just always `null`.

I guess I should mention that I did application routing like this:

```
Route::controller('news', 'NewsController');
```

Comment: Is `getEdit` really called before `getIndex`?

Comment: Yes. I know this because if `News::findOrFail($id)` doesn't fail it will load view, and if news is not found it should go to `catch`. This also works. Tried echoing `$e->getMessage()`

Comment: Have you tried `Redirect::to('news')->with('message', 'your_message');` ?

Comment: I tried that first, because I was using that before, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even work when I do `Session::put('message', Lang::get('admin.noSuchNews'))`. And when I dump session with `Session::all()` I only get csrf token `_token`

Comment: Have you [configured your session](http://laravel.com/docs/session#configuration)?

Comment: what solution have you got for this..,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I have fixed this.

Thing is, that I have put into `session.php` file this

```
'domain' => '.mydomain.com',
```

But since app is still in localhost, everything with session was failing even though I wasn't using `cookie` as my Session driver.

When I changed this to

```
'domain' => '',
```

Everything started working

Comment: I have followed your solution. But not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Check your the return state of the function setting the Session in your controller. Make sure that it returns something even if it's a simple null.

I've just had the same issue and this solved it. I was able to use the following just fine:

```
Route::get('session', function (){
    Session::put('current_user', 'Lionel Morrison');
    Session::put('user_id', '12345');

    var_dump(Session::all());
});

Route::get('get', function () {
    var_dump(Session::all());
});
```

but when I used it in a controller like so it didn't work until I returned a null;

```
public function setsession() {
    Session::put('cat', 'Tom');
    Session::put('mouse', 'Jerry');

    return null;
}

public function getsession() {
    dd(Session::all());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you find that your Session isn't saving correctly, try calling `Session::save()` explicitly to force it to save.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check the Session settings described at http://laravel.com/docs/session#session-drivers.

The easiest way is to use cookies for sessions (and make sure cookies are enabled in your browser).

If you are using `file` for storing sessions, make sure the storage path defined in `app/config/session.php` is writable.

Comment: I'm using database driver and every request creates a new row there. Some requests even create two rows in session table

Answer (score 0):

If you are tried to login using "Auth::loginUsingId()" api instead of "Auth::attempt()" api, it will destroy the session for another request. So I recommend you, use "cookie" driver instead of "file" of session.php (config\session.php\driver)

Answer (score 0):

for laravel 4.2

goto app/config dir

edit app.php

```
'url' => 'localhost',
```

edit session.php

```
'driver' => 'file',
'cookie' => 'sitename_session',
'domain' => null,
'secure' => false,
```